# dynamic dashboard primefaces 4.0

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create a small web application, a dynamic dashboard using,
`jsf-api-2.0`, `PrimesFaces4.0`, `EJB 3.1`, and `JPA2.0`

When I tried to create a dashboard component as described below:

```
dashboard = (org.primefaces.component.dashboard.Dashboard);
application.createComponent(fc, "org.primefaces.component.dashboard.Dashboard", "org.primefaces.component.dashboard.DashboardRenderer");
```

eclipse shows marker:
`The type javax.el.ValueExpression cannot be resolved.`

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

All libraries above are present in classpath !

Could you, please, explain me how can I do ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when i open the jsf-api-2.0.jar, i found the package javax.faces.el, but isn't

when I developed the library jsf-api-2.0.jar I find the package javax.faces.el, but it was not enough apparently I had to add the javax.el library.
this is normal ?